# I can't use Word 2021 with Visual Basic under Visual studio 2022

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-word

Until now, I uses VBA. But I want to use a more modern solution with Visual Studio and Visual Basic.

But I had an error message when I click on the button of my `userForm`:

Error message: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID.

Here is, my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Form1
    Dim oWrd As Word.Application

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            oWrd = New Word.Application
            oWrd.Visible = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description & " " & Err.Number)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I added Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library. Is Word 2021 not compatible with Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library?

Thank you for your disponibility.

Comment: Word 2021 is still Word 16.

Comment: I'd guess the app defaults to X64 and you have office x86 installed.

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit DLL (and vice versa).

1. Recompile your x64 service as x86 and then the 32-bit DLL can be loaded.
2. Get a 64-bit version of the COM DLL (if available), Get a 64-bit version of the World2021.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't understand. My Word is already a 64-bit and I loaded all tools for develop in Window environment with Visual Studio 2022. It doesn't work. It despairs me !!!

Comment: The error message in the question is not complete, can you provide the complete error message?